# create .txt file in php datewise

Tags: php

Hi i have a  php file using  that code i am creating  a .txt file  with a particuler name i want to create that .txt file date wise which i am unable to achieve

Here is my code
**index.php**

```
  <?php
      $content = "some text here";
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/myText.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
    ?>
```

How can i achieve my desired output

Any help will be apprecieted

Thanku

Comment: What do you mean by "datewise"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add today date as a filename

```
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/".date('Y-m-d').".txt","wb");
```

Comment: i am writing something like this but not working   $myfile = fopen("/".date(y-m-d).".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

Comment: use the full path with document root to outer directory and make sure that outer directory permission must be 0777. Hope this would help you...

Comment: i am getting this error    Warning: fopen(2014/09/22.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\xampp\htdocs\crm1\testing.php on line 68
Unable to open file!

Answer (score 1):

just add current timestamp infront of your file name and you can generate file datewise..

```
 <?php
    $content = "some text here";
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/".date('Y-m-d')."myText.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like that:

```
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/'.date('Y_m_d').'.log', $content, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: i am  getting warning and file is not creating